# architecture-independent performance monitor tool

Tags: performance, architecture, compiler, .profile

I got to know "perf" tool in "linux-tools-3.2.0-43" for Ubuntu 12.04 which can monitor the performance counts for some micro-architectures, however, the tool is dependent to the cpu architecture and compiler.

As I am interested in profiling the compiler transformations (mostly with LLVM), does anybody know any other profiling tools acting independently on the feature of the source code (like CFG, skeleton, etc.)?

Edited: In addition, I have tried to use perf in VM (monolithic), but it seems to be not monitoring kernel micro-architectures. Is it generally possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found a good scholarly tool and framework called MICA : "Microarchitecture-Independent Characterization of Application" which has been developed by Ghent University.

More Info [on the GitHub page](https://github.com/boegel/MICA)